# If code is placed within an anonymous function, why can I access it from the console?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've noticed that Meteor's production ready code is concatenated, minified, and then wrapped in an anonymous function.

In theory, this should make the Meteor object and its methods inaccessible through the DOM / window object / console.

**Why can I still access objects placed within an anonymous function through the console?**

Comment: without seeing their code i would assume they assign some global variable within the function: ie `window.meteor = ...` same way jquery and other libraries do

Comment: @PatrickEvans that's an interesting point, but I couldn't find it anywhere in the production application's code: [here's a link to the raw .js file](https://atmospherejs.com/8d85e49d0b7bfbe6c3d7288bab84c7792e0575d1.js).

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you access Meteor within the console.

Comment: @AnthonyDJ Use the Meteor object. For example: `Meteor.disconnect()` will disconnect you from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is function scoped, which means the outer function variables are accessible (and editable!) by inner functions. This goes all the way up to global (window) variables. For example:

```
(function() {
  window.t ='foo';
})();
```

If you run that code in the console, then see what `t` is, you'll see you created/changed it from within the function. Meteor globally scopes a few variables (`Meteor`, `check`, etc.) so you can access them, in addition to any variables you scope yourself when you create a package. This is because each `.js` file is also an anonymous function & if you didn't export some variables, you'd have to write everything in 1 big file. By only exporting the variables you need, your project stays modular. Hope this helps!